# AI Notebook not loading up

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

I started learning BigQuery and AI Notebook, more specifically this [Google Code Labs tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/health-data-analytics-1/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0)

I am facing some issues in creating a AI notebook and I think it is something related to permissions or roles on IAM Admin.

Here is the role that currently my project and my Notebook have,

[image: Project Role]
[image: Notebook Role]

Attaching screenshot of my Notebook instance as well.

[image]

Can anyone please help me guiding the right role to be able to run this tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in [the first page of the training](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/health-data-analytics-1/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0), you will need the role of “Owner”.